# How to query table and sum up certain columns by criteria, but not others?

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery

From a starting table, let's say:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 99 |
| 2 | 2 | 88 |
| 3 | 3 | 77 |

I'm trying to write a query that would result in a table with a different value in column C based on the criteria that when A has value `2`, the value for C should be the existing value + the value from C where A is `1`. Here's the result:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 99 |
| 2 | 2 | 187 |
| 3 | 3 | 77 |

Unsure if a grouping makes sense here, especially since there might be multiple similar criteria. The closes query I could think of would be

```
SELECT A, B, C+(SELECT C FROM table1 WHERE A=1 LIMIT 1) FROM table1 WHERE A=2;
```

but this isn't valid SQL, since subqueries can't be used like this. Any suggestions are welcome, even if they involve somehow altering the structure of the original table.

Comment: Is it more generally going to be current row plus previous row or is it more complex than that?

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? Don't tag-spam!

Comment: @FlexYourData row + some other row, could be previous, could be following.

Comment: @jarlh fair. I'm on BigQuery. Will remove other tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    A,
    B,
    CASE
        WHEN A=2 THEN C + (SELECT C FROM table WHERE A = 1)
        ELSE C
    END AS C
FROM
    table;
```

Answer (score 2):

consider below approach (tested in BigQuery)

```
select a, b, c + 
  case a 
    when 2 then sum(if(a = 1, c, 0)) over()
    else 0
  end c
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]